# How do you write a UDP port forwarder?

Tags: networking, udp

As UDP is a connectionless protocol, once the forwarder gets a packet and sends it to a target ip, and the target ip responds with data, how can the forwarder know what ip to send the packet to?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a standard gateway, it knows where to send it because the packet has a destination IP address and port.

If you are talking about NAT, then the router must remember what it has recently sent out and accept corresponding incoming packets. The router maintains a session internally, which will stay alive for some configured period.

Comment: No I mean a software UDP port forwarder. How can you keep a session if there is no connection?

Comment: When you send a packet, remember (source port, destination ip, destination port).

When you recieve, compare the packet to these records.

These records are your session.